# ionic4-iOS white screen in iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic4, mobile-development

I'm using XCode11 and ionic4. cordova version ios@5.0.0

project builds successfully using ionic cordova build ios
also successfull build in xcode
but when running on simulator, it end up showing white screen and nothing happens next. here is the console output showing the issues:

[Log1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9M31g.png)

[Log2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5nQb.png)

stuck on this for 4 days. checked so many suggestions on ionic blogs and nothing worked so far. I regret using ionic because its very buggy/unstable... please help

ISSUES:

> -Failed to load webpage with error: the operation couldnt be completed(NSURLErrorDomain error -999)
>
> -NSURL Connection finished with error -code -1100
>
> -ERROR: HTTP Request(OSRequestRegisterUser) must contain an app_id parameter
>
> -ERROR: Encountered error during push registration with OneSignal

in addition to the above errors, the iOS simulator hangs on "White Screen", the application does not load and nothing happens next.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

On your xcode, navigate to your plugin folder, locate a file named OneSignalPush.m

Inside, locate the initOneSignalObject,

add this: `appId = "your-app-id-here";`

right after this code:

`[OneSignal setValue:@"Cordova" forKey:@"mSDKType"];`

That did the trick for me.